# Rebuilding Google Fonts with Open Type Features

Tags: fonts

I want to use the Playfair Display font with lining numbers (not the old-style nums that come as default)

I had a play around on font squirrel's webfont generator, and got something working. However the output was 33kb (compressed).

Google Fonts is able to split the font over unicode ranges, so you can get away with downloading just a 11kb font (compressed)

Does anybody know how to get a good, optimised output like Google Fonts?

Comment: Why? What makes 33kb objectionable?

Comment: I guess. I just know it's possible to get it a third of the size

Comment: Splitting the font is called subsetting, and any decent font editor including the free Font Forge will let you create a subset font. Just make sure that the font license says you can do what you're doing. Not all webfonts may be edited.